# Migrating from SYBASE SQLAnywhere 11.0 to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, sqlanywhere, sql-server-2008r2-express

Hello everyone i have got a project to migrate from SQLAnywhere 11 to any new relational databases for our ship crew web application.The reasons for migrating is cost and support issues.I will need to choose a database which is free and has all features as SQLAnywhere 11.0.

Here is the list of Questions i want to know about SQL Server 2008 R2 express.

1. Do we have any migration utility to move from SQL Anywhere 11 to SQL Server 2008 R2 express.
2. How easy is deployment of  SQL Server 2008 R2 express from install shield MSI.
3. Alternative methods to migrate from SQLAnyhere 11 to SQL server 2008 R2 express.
4. Do management tools come free with express addition. I should be able to defragment and  restore    the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Sybase (v 5.1 was released just this week), but I am not familiar enough with SQL Anywhere to assure you whether, or how well, it works:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/07/12/announcing-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-v-5-1.aspx

Deployment of SQL Server Express is relatively easy, but I haven't done any work recently incorporating this into a more complex installer.

If you use Express w/Tools or Express w/Advanced Services, they come with Management Studio Express. You can also download this separately:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985

Note that Management Studio Express is missing some of the SSMS functionality, such as managing agent, so if you have to manage other editions you may be better off investing $49 (or less, depending on vendor) into the [developer edition](http://www.google.com/search?q=buy+developer+edition+SQL+Server+2008+R2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=buy+developer+edition+SQL+Server+2008+R2&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Mj4&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=s0ogTqLZNM600AHqrrySAw&ved=0CJMBEK0E&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=76c270e3648d5fe9&biw=1803&bih=1398), which comes with the full version of SSMS.